# Check if State is empty when transferring to a new page

Tags: reactjs, state

This is my `/chat` page this is called from the `/login` page. I pass this chat page some data with

```
 // this is inside of the page /login
 history.push({
                pathname: '/chat',
                state: {
                  email: email,
                  name: password,
                },
              })
```

The problem is when I access `/chat` from `/login` everything works, but when I access `/chat` only I get the error `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'email' of 'state' as it is undefined`.

Is there an option to query if state is empty? And if so take null?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function Chat() {


    const { state } = useLocation();
    const { email } = state;
    const [person, setPerson] = useState([]);
    const test_test = { email }

    useEffect(() => {

        axios.get('localhost:8000/'.concat('FILLER_', email.toString()))
        .then((res) => {
          const datapersons = res.data;
          setPerson( datapersons );
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
      }, []);



return (
    <div>
        <h1>Welcome {person.givenname}</h1>
    </div>
);
}

export default Chat
```

Comment: That state is only present on navigation, so if you refresh the page or visit the page directly you won't have it (which is the issue you described). Storing data across pages is what [HTTP cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) are for, or you could store the info in [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to save the data somewhere but query if empty then put something in there so that no error occurs

Answer (score 1):

The issue is when you go to /chat by itself you are not passing the link data to the new route anymore. This means that when you try to get state from useLocation() it won't be there as you didn't pass the data from login.

A solution I would recommend would be to cache the data in the browser and if you don't have useLocation() state you can then get it from the cached data. When you login you can save the information you want to the local cache [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)  is some more detailed information on how to accomplish that. Wherever you login I would use

```
window.localStorage.setItem('email', 'userEmail');
```

and then in your component

```
const { email } = state ? state : window.localStorage.getItem('email');
```

And then when you log out make sure to clear out local storage unless you want to keep the user logged in between sessions you could use localStorage to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether `state` exists before accessing it:

```
const email = state == null ? null : state.email;
```

If you're using TypeScript you can use the `?.` syntax:

```
const email = state?.email;
```